# waiting for user input in R from terminal

Tags: r, rstudio

I was able to wait for user input in R when running my script as Rscipt myscript.R from the command line as follows and reading the input from stdin.

```
cat("Enter word : ")
word <- readLines(file("stdin"),1)
print(word);
```

However, when I try to do it from the terminal using the below code, it just goes to the next line without taking user input. How do I overcome this?

```
word <- readline(prompt="Enter a word: ")
print(word);
```

Answer (score 5):

The "user" input is the line after `readline`.
Try this:

```
word <- readline(prompt="Enter a word: ")
Hello world!
print(word)
```

#### Update

To wait for input in the console:

```
word <- readline(prompt="Enter a word: "); print(word)
```

or

```
{
  word <- readline(prompt="Enter a word: ")
  print(word)
}
```

Comment: I was actually copying the lines word <- readline(prompt="Enter a word: ")print(word) and wanting that to work. Is there a way for that?

Comment: @PepperBoy Yes, add semicolon: `word <- readline(prompt="Enter a word: "); print(word)`. Enter the word in the console when prompted.

Comment: That is working for me in interactive mode, but not in a script.

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms Yes, the question was about interactive mode.

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms you can allways use `if(interactive()) ...`

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to top of your program:

```
args<-commandArgs(TRUE)
```

and then give input with the Rscript line as:

```
Rscript filename.r args[1] args[2] ...
```

Comment: I don't think this answers OP's question