# R skips lines in a function

Tags: r, function, readline

I have the following function which requires a sequence of user inputs:

```
fun <- function(){ 


  cat("Hello! let's input some data")

  x <- readline("Input foo: ")
  y <- readline("Input bar: ")
  z <- readline("Input baz: ")
  a <- readline("Input foobarbaz: ")

}

fun()
```

However, when I call `fun()` after the function is defined, it often skips 
directly to the second input - `Input bar:` why is `readlines()` asynchronous in a function?  Does it have to do with assigning the input to a variable?

In the console:

```
> fun()
Hello! let's input some dataInput foo: 
Input bar:
```

I would like the inputs to appear in the same order as they are written in the function.

Why does this happen and what is the workaround?

Comment: How often? I can't reproduce it with several tries.

Comment: See this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012056/r-how-do-i-prompt-the-user-for-input-from-the-console

Comment: It might not be reproducible with a short amount of code as above, but `readline()` doesn't necessarily wait for the first input before it jumps to the next input.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any [wait function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544217/waiting-for-user-input-in-r-from-terminal), but maybe depends on [how the code is run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245442/wait-for-user-input-from-keyboard-in-r-before-next-line-of-code-readline-rst)?

Comment: I've found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112370/make-readline-wait-for-input-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that the next statement goes on a new line.

```
cat("Hello! let's input some data", sep="\n")
```

Comment: What is the new output? Please give me more to go off

Comment: The same problem persists of intermittently skipping to the second input, even after adding `sep = "\n"`

Comment: OP isn't worried about which line things print on. The problem is that `readline()` is supposed to wait for user input before proceeding, but OP never gets a chance to enter the first input before the second input is requested.